# Apply click Binding to a generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I want to create a tooltip dynamically with menu items and apply click events to them, The HTML looks like this:

```
 <div data-bind="text:'Menu', attr:{title:viemModel.menu()}"></div>
```

The view model has a method called menu which adds some tooltip content as shown:

```
menu = () ->
"""
<div>
  <a data-bind="click:viewModel.item1">Item 1</a>
  <a data-bind="click:viewModel.item2">Item 2</a>
</div>
"""
```

where item1 and item2 are two more functions inside the view model. But since the bindings have already been applied on DOM load, the new bindings for item does not work.
Is there a way I can add title attribute on DOM load itself, if not how can the bindings be applied dynamically?

Comment: Am I not clear?? Why is no one replying???

Comment: probably a fiddle will help.